# Deploy zalenium on AWS cloud environment

Tags: zalenium

We have a requirement to spin more than 50 selenium containers parallelly on zalenium. The current infrastructure we have doesn't support this requirement. I want to know if anyone deployed zalenium on cloud environment and used ECS or EKS services to achieve this?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?